# HTML - An editable paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code :

(HTML)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Editable Paragraph</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label onclick="changeText(0);" class="edit-button"></label>
    <h1 id="h1">Editable Paragraph</h1>
    <br>
    <label onclick="changeText(1);" class="edit-button"></label>
    <p id="p1">Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! </p>
    <br>
    <label onclick="changeText(2);" class="edit-button"></label>
    <p id="p2">Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! </p>
  </body>

  <footer>
    <div id="newText">
      <input id="myNewText" type="text" name="myNewText"/>
    </div>
  </footer>
</html>
```

(CSS)

```
p {
  display:inline;
}

h1 {
  display:inline;
}

#newText {
  position:fixed;
  left:5px;
  right:auto;
  top:auto;
  bottom:5px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#cccccc;
}

.edit-button {
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background-color:#cccccc;
}

.edit-button:hover {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

(JS (not jQuery))

```
/* Smart Tips

1. When adding / editing add <br> before new <label>.

*/

function changeText(var count){
  switch (count) {
    case 0:
      document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myNewText").value;
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("p"+count).innerHTML = document.getElementById("myNewText").value;
  }
}
```

After clicking the button, nothing happened.
I am going to try looking at the console.

Comment: remove var from function parameter

Comment: can you copy your comment and answer this question, @Manwal? So i can accept your answer,

Comment: did you take a look or thought about the attribute  `contenteditable` ?

Comment: quite a good idea! contenteditable is sometimes better but this, is also another quite good style!

Comment: right, it is another approach. (this was what i first thought of :  http://jsfiddle.net/bnG92/ )

Comment: then what is `<input type="text>` for?? using up the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for my case:

```
function changeText(count){
  switch (count) {
    case 0:
      document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myNewText").value;
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("p"+count).innerHTML = document.getElementById("myNewText").value;
  }
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3V3r/1/)